# Pass variables to the remotely imported powershell module

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am trying to create new PSSession, import ActiveDirectory module on the remote machine and then import-pssession to my local workstation - this works fine. The code looks like:

```
$rs = New-PSSession -ComputerName RemoteMachine
Invoke-Command -Session $rs -scriptblock {import-module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession -Session $rs -Module Active Directory
```

And now I am able to call ActiveDirectory cmdlets, so e.g. `Get-ADUser -Filter *` works fine.

BUT

I am not able to pass variables to the ActiveDirectory cmdlets, I am not able to execute the following:

```
$name = 'John Smith'
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq $name}
```

It says `$name` is not defined. I cannot pass the variable to the `Get-ADUser`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: try: http://get-powershell.com/post/2008/12/14/Passing-Variables-to-a-Remote-PSSession-in-CTP-3.aspx

Comment: Let me know! Vote my comment if it works!

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following: `Invoke-Command -Session $rs -ArgumentList $name -ScriptBlock {param ($name) Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq $name}}` This works fine. BUT I am still wondering, why I am not able to pass variables directly to the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet? Why I have to do it thourgh `invoke-command`?

Comment: $name is a local session variable, this is the fact. Read also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/29/arguments-for-remote-commands.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it now but try to use double quotes instaed of a script block so the value of the variable can be expanded before it moves on to the target,

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq $name"
```